# How can i get my device back now in operating system? Which is lost forever once i executed my command

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, linux-kernel, usb

I have a USB camera connected i needed to reset it or power off and power on, because it get lost often from /dev/video0 or 1.

After trying this following code, it seems to be working for my goal.

it powers off the usb device correctly and then powers on correctly.

Everything seems fine except the big problem now faced, the moment i rebooted my system, now using lsusb i do not see my usb device any more. (when i try with another PC, same OS or different OS, the device works perfectly only in this PC its completely dead since i ran my following code)

Can anyone explain why it happened and How do i get back this `"046d:082d"` device now on this machine?

```
#!/bin/bash
usb="046d:082d"
cam=$(lsusb | awk "/$usb/ {print $6}")
echo $cam
if [ ! -z "$cam" -a "$cam" != " " ]; then
  for X in /sys/bus/usb/devices/*;
  do
    a=$(cat "$X/idVendor" 2>/dev/null)
    b=$(cat "$X/idProduct" 2>/dev/null)
    c="$a:$b"
    if [ ! -z "$c" -a "$c" != " " ] && [ "$c" == "$usb" ]; then
      d=$(echo $X | sed "s/\/sys\/bus\/usb\/devices\///g")
      echo "[FOUND] $d"
      # Power down
      echo ROOT_PASS | sudo -S sh -c "echo 0 > /sys/bus/usb/devices/$d/authorized"
      sleep 2
      # Power up
      echo ROOT_PASS | sudo -S sh -c "echo 1 > /sys/bus/usb/devices/$d/authorized"
      lsusb
      break

    fi
  done;
fi
```

Comment: Did you add any udev rules (and forgot to remove them)?... :)

Comment: Also ensure that the usb-host (`usbX`), you are connecting the device to, authorises devices by default. Run the following command `echo 1 > /sys/bus/usb/devices/usbX/authorized_default` and then disconnect and re-insert the usb-camera.

Comment: In Step 1: the camera was working showing in lsusb Step 2: because the driver was not compatible i needed to power off and on so that script worked for me Step 3: the moment since i applied that script no more now lsusb showing Step 4: i have rebooted few times but no luck camera does not show . To your question no i did not necessarily used udev and echo 1 was applied before it was lost forever in this system. the camera itself is working in other system only on this system its screwed. Any other thougts?

Comment: As you can also see my all files authorized_default is 1 example: $ `cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/authorized_default
1
1
1
1
`

Comment: Can you share the output of `dmesg` when you plug-in the camera?...